# Outlook Web App on Exchange 2010 - User added an image to his email signature in OWA, now cannot edit signature

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

[Using a method like the one described here](http://www.wimesh.net/wimesh/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=30&Itemid=30), a user who shall not be named (cough cough not me) hastily added an image to his email signature in OWA for Exchange 2010 w/ SP2. Now, that said user cannot edit his email signature! When crafting new emails the signature does appear. I assume this is a situation that the developers of OWA simply did not prepare for, but I am wondering if there is any resolution:

1. Is there some way of dealing with this issue head-on in OWA's options?
2. Is there some way of resetting a user's OWA "profile" in Exchange 2010 or the PowerShell CLI for it?
3. Is there any hope for being able to change this signature other than recreating the mailbox? It is a terribly annoying issue because the phone number <strike>I had listed</strike> the user listed there is wrong, and the image URL that it is linked to is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638117.aspx) EMS command with the -SignatureHTML and/or -SignatureText argument to reset the signature.

Comment: You are a great man sir! I didn't see this answer for a while, but tested and it works like a charm. To be more specific, use `Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration -Identity jdoe -SignatureHTML ""` to blank out the signature so your user can re edit it without the bad stuff.